# iPhone - reverse geocoding gives a "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PBRequesterErrorDomain error 6001.)" error

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, reverse-geocoding

I have a simple app that shows a MapView.
When the user scrolls or change the zoom position on the mapview, I want to display the country name that is on the center of the map.

So I do this :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.mapView.centerCoordinate];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.countryNameLabel.text = @"";
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    self.countryNameLabel.text = placemark.country;
}

- (void) reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.countryNameLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The regionDidChangeAnimated method is only called when the view has finished scrolling, so no more that 1 call per second.

Sometimes, I have the "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PBRequesterErrorDomain error 6001.)" error so I can't display the country name.
Moving a little bit the mapview can solve the problem so the country is displayed.

How can I ensure that I will be able to display the country name each time the user changes the map view display ?

I've read [that post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/31883-pbrequestererrordomain-errors-reverse-geocoding.html) but that does not help.

Comment: just to know, have you try to start the reverse geocoding in the mapViewDidFinishingLoadingMap: ?

Comment: @Mat : does not work. Smae problem sometimes. And the most of time, the method is not triggered as the content of the map is already loaded (for example when zooming in, then moving)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trap that error, and try another rev geocoding service, such as [Yahoo Placefinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) when Google is not cooperating.